# What can I be? (Second attempt)

Tags: word, language

> I exist in many languages
> In these languages, I exist in many forms
>
> In the most common language, I am defined as **breathable**
> In an ethnic group which has the same name as a programming language, I am defined as **drinkable**
> Whereas in Welsh, I am defined as **readable**

What can I be?

Comment: Instead of naming your puzzles after which puzzle posting number they are, please give them a more meaningful name. Many people will use the title of a puzzle posting to give an extra hint or bit of commentary on the puzzle, and many people who are posting riddles will choose to select one (often central) line of their riddle and make that the title as well.  For this one, maybe something like "Breathe me, drink me, read me - name me!" might work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it:

> **Air**?

In the most common language, I am defined as breathable

> In English, it's air

In an ethnic group which has the same name as a programming language, I am defined as drinkable

> **Java** is both a programming language and Indonesian group. Water in Indonesian language is *air* 
>  [image]

Whereas in Welsh, I am defined as readable

> *Word* corresponds to **air** in Welsh. *Thanks @PuzzledPig* 
>  [image]

Comment: Perhaps the third definition at [this link](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-meaning-of/welsh-word-d1d9b9355fa9cd3e4b1949bbb0844e83dfa1c854.html) would help for the last line?

Comment: Nice, will add this!